# What can be most scable approach of download functionality?

Tags: mongoose, rabbitmq, bigdata, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are currently developing attendance system (based on IN and OUT logs) where a client can download last 6 months data of their employees. Currently we are facing issue when data set is very large. Currently we are using Mongo as our primary database to serve download functionality. Both fetching and writing it to excel is heavy operation. 
I know certain ways to solve this problem. I am listing all those and want you to help me in deciding most scalable option.

a) Increase the server configuration.

b) Move the entire data in pre-processed format in some other database (like elastic search) in separate micro service. This will reduce my data fetching time.

c) As writing data in excel for 5 to 10 million entries is itself memory consuming process. Should we implement data writing in excel through a queue (Kafka or rabbitmq) with multiple pods of Kubernetes with single or limited number of request at a time ?

d) combination of option b & option c.

Please help me out with your suggestion and let me know if there is some other scalable solution.

Comment: when downloading this data, is there is an option to specify multiple filters ? like data-range, include some users, exclude some users, particular department data etc?

Comment: Yes data can be filtered out.

Comment: done.....please upvote the question if you think it was useful @user156327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are using `MongoDB` for fetching and filtering the data, which as you mentioned are not in a pre-processed format.

**MongoDB or other document-based NoSQL like DynamoDB is very good when you store data in the denormalized format and then get it based on id, or with just a few filters**, even for efficient filtering of the data, you need to create index(similar to MySQL index), which takes extra space and these are not cached by default.

Good use of above are showing the product details page on e-commerce sites, where these data are normally stores in normalized format to support ACID, but then also in `denormalized format in NoSQL` to support faster reads and there you don't search, But still search on e-commerce comes through inverted index only .

**You can get filtered data very fast if you use the filters in your elasticsearch queries** [see the official doc for filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context)

> Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch,
>   to speed up performance.

**This would solve your issue of fetching a million docs**, and after that, as you already mentioned, you should use the queuing mechanism to write this huge data and Kafka is very popular and fits in this use-case perfectly.

**P.S:- No need to increase the server configurations, the right design will solve the issue and adding more hardware is just fighting the symptom and not solving the root cause.**